# Downloading zip files without URL link from website using R

Tags: r

I am looking to download the zip files displayed on this website using R: https://www.ffiec.gov/npw/FinancialReport/FinancialDataDownload?selectedyear=2021

I would traditionally use download.file() to download the files directly using a URL link, but the zip files don't contain a URL link, so I've been trying to use alternative scraping methods using rvest, but am having no luck. Would really appreciate the help. Thank you

Comment: URL is `https://www.ffiec.gov/npw/FinancialReport/ReturnBHCFZipFiles?zipfilename=BHCF20210930.ZIP` etc.

Comment: Wow, magic, thank you!